# angular 5 why the change does not work within the mat-menu

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2, angular-material-5

why it does not work (change) inside a mat-menu.

this is the code that I have

```
<mat-menu #texpublicity="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="size">Tamaño de letra</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="type">Tipo de letra</button>
  <input type="color" (change)="changeColorLetters($event.target.value)" >
</mat-menu>

  changeColorLetters(color : string){
     this.colorLetters = color;
  }
```

in this way it works correctly

```
<mat-menu #texpublicity="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="size">Tamaño de letra</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="type">Tipo de letra</button>
</mat-menu>

 <div>
    <input type="color" (change)="changeColorLetters($event.target.value)" >
 </div>


  changeColorLetters(color : string){
     this.colorLetters = color;
  }
```

the input works when it is outside the mat-menu, does not work inside, is there some way that it can work within the mat-menu, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't we try using ElementRef.

```
<mat-menu #texpublicity="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="size">Tamaño de letra</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="type">Tipo de letra</button>
  <input type="color" #colorElem>
</mat-menu>
```

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('colorElem') colorElem : ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.colorElem.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', 
     (event)=>{
        // handle click here
     });
}
```

Comment: but that's the click event, that only returns the default value that the input has, because when I make a color change it does not work

Comment: change the click event to change and try again

Comment: I already did it but for some reason it does not work it never enters the method

Comment: Sorry, it should be 'change' instead of click.

Comment: Yes, it's weird that it does not work, but anyway, thanks, it works, I did it in another way,

Comment: Created a stackblitz and it worked. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlbo4m. Might be using inside 'mat-menu' is causing issue. what is the fix